# Aborting Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` for achieving parallelism, I was wondering is there any way that I can stop the execution of `Parallel.ForEach` once any one the requests complete. For example consider the following code:

```
IEnumerable<string> myList = new List<string>() { "admin", "admin2", "admin3" };
CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Parallel.ForEach(myList,
    admin_name =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(admin_name);
    });
```

The above code prints `admin`,`admin2` and `admin3`. I want to stop further execution if any of the admin names is printed.

Is this achievable? Or is there any work around available?

I am open to suggestions and improvement.

Comment: Relevant MSDN article: [**How to: Cancel a Parallel.For or ForEach Loop**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's **much** easier using `ParallelLoopState` (another `ForEach` overload has a 2nd parameter for `action`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which passes a [`ParallelLoopState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate(v=vs.110).aspx) to your delegate, this can be use to break out of the `Parallel.ForEach`, i.e:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myList, (admin_name, state) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(admin_name);

    // Stop other iterations
    state.Stop();
});
```

What you will need to bear in mind is that this will not be atomic, other delegates which have already started will continue to execute, unless they explicitly check `state.IsStopped`.

Instead of `ParallelLoopState.Stop()` you may desire `ParallelLoopState.Break()`.

Some further information about `Stop()` and `Break()` can be found at [How to: Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the reason for the downvote and I will try to correct any mistake I have made?